# Samsung Galaxy S7 stuck at boot - power button not working in recovery mode

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-s7

my Samsung Galaxy S7 is stuck in boot with the "no command" error screen. I found out I can possibly fix the problem by wiping the cache partition, and have found the recovery menu to do this.

However, my power button does not seem to work in the recovery menu (it does work for powering the S7 on, however. Thus, I can not select the menu item to wipe the cache partition.

How can I get rid of the no command error? If wiping the cache partition is the right way, what am I doing wrong? I don't want to factory reset my device.

I am not usnig a modified version - I use the android version shipped by Samsung

Answer (score 0):

My power button will work after scrolling to the option using the volume keys but I've always wondered about what it says below the options for the hashtree lineup..